# Read mail using python with smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtp, imaplib

I'm able to send mail using python script , here is my code

```
import smtplib, ssl 

smtp_server = "xxx.yyyy.com"
sender_email = "abcd@efgh.com"
receiver_email = "mnop@efgh.com"
username ='DRAETWK'
password = 'password'
message = """\
Subject: Test Mail

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server) as server:   
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
    print('Mail Sent... Check your inbox')
```

Mail send code is working but when I use the same user details I'm not able to read my mail I'm getting login FAILED issue , here is the code

```
import imaplib
import email.header
from smtplib import SMTP as SMTP


host = 'xxx.yyyy.com'
user = 'abcd@efgh.com'

login_user= 'qweqwr'
password = 'xsw2zsadsadaaq1'


# Connect to the server
print('Connecting to ' + host)
mailBox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
mailBox.debug = 100
print(mailBox)
# Login to our account
mailBox.login(login_user, password)
```

can someone help ?

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\imaplib.py", line 582, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'LOGIN failed.'

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. Have you checked if the server firewall allows IMAP connections? Most email servers disable this by default. 

For example, if you're using Gmail here's a guide on how to enable IMAP https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en

Comment: mine is working for gmail , now I'm trying with outlook in my office network

Comment: Ah, good to know! Have you spoken with your office IT team to ensure your office email servers allow IMAP and allow external IP connections?